# Disable paging in selector - scroll only

Tags: acumatica

I've received a question on if it's possible and how to disable the paging option of certain selector fields and instead enable full scrolling of values.

Ultimately I have already discussed the negative effects of doing so in regards to performance, memory utilization, speed, etc.

In looking into it though, at first I thought it would be a simple item of setting the AllowPaging option to false but this doesn't seem to be all that's needed.

If I in my selector field (inventory lookup in sales order for example) add the following (XML view)

```
        <PXSegmentMask DataField="InventoryID" ParentId="phG_tab_Items#0_grid_Levels#0_edInventoryID" TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXSegmentMask">
            <Prop Key="GridProperties.AllowPaging" Value="False" />
        </PXSegmentMask>
```

The resulting view does indeed disable the paging options on the selector however the resulting record count shown is still the same.

Looking at the generated SQL query, i can see it does indeed now select all the records but looking at the overflow property on the div I see that it's set to "hidden" for the vertical scroll bars.

That leads me to believe that the Scroll settings need to be adjusted but the PXSelector does not expose scroll settings in GridProperties.

Short of setting the pagesize to int.Max value, is there something else that I'm missing or is this perhaps a build issue?

Thanks